# How do i create a .so file that contains only C++ code wrapped in C code - OpenCV related?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, wrapper

On Ubuntu Saucy 64bit in termial using g++ Im attempting to wrap OpenCV in a language without a strong C++ ffi so im attempting to use C++ to C wrappers to aid in doing this... Here is the small peice of the files Im trying to convert just to get a feel for it(opencv_generated.hpp and opencv_generated.cpp at this link https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv-raw)

opencv_generated hpp:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#ifndef __OPENCV_GENERATED_HPP
#define __OPENCV_GENERATED_HPP
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace flann;
using namespace cvflann;
extern "C" {
Mat* cv_imread(String* filename, int flags);
void cv_imshow(String* winname, Mat* mat);
bool cv_imwrite(String* filename, Mat* img, vector_int* params);}
```

opencv_generated.cpp:

```
#include "opencv_generated.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace flann;
using namespace cvflann;
extern "C" {

Mat* cv_imread(String* filename, int flags) {
   return new Mat(cv::imread(*filename, flags));
}
void cv_imshow(String* winname, Mat* mat) {
   cv::imshow(*winname, *mat);
}
bool cv_imwrite(String* filename, Mat* img, vector_int* params) {
   return cv::imwrite(*filename, *img, *params);
}}
```

Am new to C wrappers for C++ and am trying to compile with

```
   g++ -Wall -dynamiclib  -I/home/w/test/opencv_generated.hpp 
  -I/home/w/test/opencv_generated.cpp  -o test.so
```

im getting error:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

...im in the directory my opencv_generated.cpp and opencv_generated.hpp files are in so what am i doing wrong??....any help == greatly valued=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `-I` parameter to the compiler should only be a path to a directory you wish to include, not necessarily a file. Also, your second `-I` parameter seems to be the source file you want to compile, so you wouldn't have to precede this with anything.  If you're in the same directory as the two .hpp and .cpp files you shouldn't have to specify the include directory for the opencv_generated.hpp file either -- you can just compile with the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libTest.so opencv_generated.cpp
```

If you're in another directory and/or your source + header files are scattered around, though, you'll probably have to compile your source with absolute paths like you originally posted:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libTest.so -I/home/w/test/ /home/w/test/opencv_generated.cpp
```

Additionally, if you were linking another program you wrote (say, main.cpp) against this shared library and were in the same directory as it, you'd run:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -L/home/w/test/ -lTest
```

Where `/home/w/test/` contains the file `libTest.so`. By default, the compiler will look for your `libTest.so` file in the current library path when you specify `-lTest` and will not be found, so the `-L` parameter is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much... g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o opencv_generated.so opencv_generated.cpp worked